# Resize echo text

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a page that displays text the user typed in a form before that. If the user types a lot in the form and submits, the page that displays the text has a horizontal scroll bar. How could I make the text automatically do a line break after the text fills the screen? It needs to be 8.5 x 11 so it will print. What should I do to the textbox/display page? Here's some code I used:
 
text area:

```
<textarea name="body" id="textarea">
```

display page:

```
  <h3>
    <?php echo "$body"; ?> <br />
    </h3>
```

When the text is sent using post and get, it is encoded and decoeded. Thanks..

Comment: You really shouldn't have a `<br>` inside your `<h3>`... set a proper margin instead.

Comment: How about using a `media="print"` stylesheet to address the printing problems?

Comment: Not sure if I quite understand... What are you suggesting I put under @media print { ? the width? Thanks.

Comment: note: you can just `echo $body;`, the double quotes aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) to get it done on the PHP side.

But you could just use a `div` with a predefined width:

```
<h3 style="width: 8.4in;">
    <?php echo "$body"; ?> <br />
</h3>
```

Comment: It is not working - What do you see? Try to set a background-color that stands out, it is easier to validate, and make sure and make sure that your display style is set block (or other block type).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you could do here is to set a width on your `<h3>` element. Since you need it to fit within 8.5x11", a width of 8.5" should be appropriate:

```
h3 { width: 8.5in; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply also, but I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: The text is still a long string of characters that go across the page without line breaking. Sorry that I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [word-wrap](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/) property from CSS3? Maybe you could do something like this

```
h3 { word-wrap: break-word; }
```